# maximum number for define function

Tags: c, codeblocks

I use C language for a natural language processing project.

I would like to store a dictionary file.

I used the following define statement

```
#define DICSIZE 46000
```

The question is about the number 46000 because it is the maximum number I can enter.

If I try a bigger number the program stop running.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: To solve your problem, you have to first recognize that it has nothing to do with creating this #define.... it's got everything to do with how your code is using the value.

Comment: Show at least a few usages of `DICSIZE` ...

Comment: Maybe showing the relevant parts of your program might help us to find an answer.

Comment: This may be another [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The real problem lies somewhere in your code, not define's problem. A define is just a string replacement, the preprocessor doesn't know anything about the value or anything being replaced

Answer (score 2):

Program stops not because of `DICSIZE` macro. It's usage.

I guess, some array is allocated locally(i.e In stack) by passing this macro as array size.

`int myArray[DICSIZE];`

So when the number is increased, you may face problem. I suggest to allocate memory dynamically using `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a large array declared locally in a function like this:

```
int main()
{
    MyRecordType myArray[DICSIZE];

    ...
    return 0;
}
```

When `DICSIZE` gets large, `myArray` gets large, and you run out of stack space.

Use dynamic memory allocation instead:

```
int main()
{
    MyRecordType * myArray = malloc(DICSIZE * sizeof(myArray[0]));
    assert(myArray);
    ...
    free(myArray);
    return 0;
}
```